# Can not justify columns with display: flex (NO BOOTSTRAP)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

> **Note:** Before I start asking my question, I gotta ask you not to provide solutions using Bootstrap. Thanks

Problem is: 
I have several rows. For example 2; lets say, in the first row I have 6 columns. Code will look like this:

```
<div style="display: flex;">
    <div style="flex:1;">1</div>
    <div style="flex:1;">2</div>
    <div style="flex:1;">3</div>
    <div style="flex:1;">4</div>
    <div style="flex:1;">5</div>
    <div style="flex:1;">6</div>
</div>
```

The second row contains 4 columns:

```
<div style="display: flex;">
    <div style="flex:1;">1</div>
    <div style="flex:1;">2</div>
    <div style="flex:1;">3</div>
    <div style="flex:1;">4</div>
</div>
```

As you see in [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gta2pbLf/4/) they are not justified well and not behave like rows. Is there any solution of **FLEX** when rows behave like table like:

```
<div style="display: flex;">
    <div style="flex:6;">1</div>
    <div style="flex:6;">2</div>
    <div style="flex:6;">3</div>
    <div style="flex:6;">4</div>
</div>
```

Thanks.
Regards, Nick.

Comment: How do you want them to be justified? Do you have any other css we can look at or is it all inline? What is your desired outcome?

Comment: Honestly, this seems like a question that would be best answered using [tag:css-grid], rather than flex-box.

Comment: @SmokeyDawson other css does not matter. I want to adjust rows like tables. Columns in one line. 1 (second row) beneath 1 (first row), 2 (second row) beneath 2 (first row) and s.o. Using Flexbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the max columns in the *table* you could use `flex: calc(1/max_columns)` (*in this example 6*) to accomplish it.

```html
<div style="display: flex;">
  <div style="flex:1;">1</div>
  <div style="flex:1;">2</div>
  <div style="flex:1;">3</div>
  <div style="flex:1;">4</div>
  <div style="flex:1;">5</div>
  <div style="flex:1;">6</div>
</div>

<div style="display: flex;">
  <div style="flex:calc(1/6);">1</div>
  <div style="flex:calc(1/6);">2</div>
  <div style="flex:calc(1/6);">3</div>
  <div style="flex:calc(1/6);">4</div>
</div>
```